# SciPy root gives a ValueError depending on method

Tags: python, scipy, nonlinear-equation

I am using SciPy `root` function to find a root of a function which involves an ODE (in the function passed to `root` I am calling SciPy `solve_ivp`).  When using "krylov" method in the `root`, it solves it with no problem.  But when I use any other method it raise a ValueError: `ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,1) into shape (2,)`.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Kourosh

Comment: Do you know anything about `numpy` `broadcasting`?  no?  then you haven't read enough basic `numpy`.  Or how about a traceback with the error?  My guess - just a guess - is that your objective function returns a (2,1) shape array, but it is supposed to be a (2,) shape, a flat 1d array.  Did you review the method docs, and their requirements?  Paying close attention to the shape of the parameter requirements? Clearly it's a `broadcasted` assignment issue, but the rest is just a guess.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  Yes, I know about `numpy broadcasting`.  My objective function return a scalar value.  My question is how one of the `scipy root` methods i.e., krylov solves it with no problem but other methods raise an error.

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted on the bug report (why didn't you post any of there here?):

```
In [1]: from scipy.optimize import root
   ...: from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
   ...: 
   ...: 
   ...: def fun_d(x, d0):
   ...:     return(d0 * x)
   ...: 
   ...: 
   ...: def ode_fun(t, z, a, b, c, d0):
   ...:     x, y = z
   ...:     d = fun_d(x, d0)
   ...:     u = a*d*x - b*x*y
   ...:     v = -c*y + d*x*y
   ...:     return([u, v])
   ...: 
   ...: 
   ...: def fun_err(d0, a, b, c):
   ...:     sol = solve_ivp(ode_fun, t_span=[0, 15], y0=[10, 5],
   ...:                     method='RK45', args=(a, b, c, d0), t_eval=[12, ],
   ...:                     rtol=1e-11, atol=1e-13)
   ...:     obj_sol = solve_ivp(ode_fun, t_span=[0, 15], y0=[10, 5],
   ...:                         method='RK45', args=(1.5, 1, 3, 1), t_eval=[12, ],
   ...:                         rtol=1e-11, atol=1e-13)
   ...:     obj_x = obj_sol.y[0][-1]
   ...:     return(sol.y[0][-1] - obj_x)
   ...: 
   ...: 
   ...: a = 1.5
   ...: b = 1
   ...: c = 3
   ...:
```

The case that runs:

```
In [2]: d_sol = root(fun_err, x0=0.5, args=(a, b, c), method='krylov')
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/_nonlin.py:366: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  and dx_norm/self.x_rtol <= x_norm))
In [3]: d_sol
Out[3]: 
     fun: array([1.82191151e-06])
 message: 'A solution was found at the specified tolerance.'
     nit: 2
  status: 1
 success: True
       x: array(0.53107372)
```

The failure case, with **FULL TRACEBACK**

```
In [4]: d_sol = root(fun_err, x0=0.5, args=(a, b, c), method='hybr')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Input In [4] in <cell line: 1>
    d_sol = root(fun_err, x0=0.5, args=(a, b, c), method='hybr')
  File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/_root.py:234 in root
    sol = _root_hybr(fun, x0, args=args, jac=jac, **options)
  File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/_minpack_py.py:226 in _root_hybr
    shape, dtype = _check_func('fsolve', 'func', func, x0, args, n, (n,))
  File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/_minpack_py.py:24 in _check_func
    res = atleast_1d(thefunc(*((x0[:numinputs],) + args)))
  Input In [1] in fun_err
    sol = solve_ivp(ode_fun, t_span=[0, 15], y0=[10, 5],
  File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/_ivp/ivp.py:580 in solve_ivp
    message = solver.step()
  File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/_ivp/base.py:181 in step
    success, message = self._step_impl()
  File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/_ivp/rk.py:144 in _step_impl
    y_new, f_new = rk_step(self.fun, t, y, self.f, h, self.A,
  File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/_ivp/rk.py:61 in rk_step
    K[0] = f
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,1) into shape (2,)
```

based on the branching in `root` source, it also works for any of these:

```
 `broyden1', 'broyden2', 'anderson', 'linearmixing',
 'diagbroyden', 'excitingmixing', 'krylov'
```

According to the `root` docs `x0` is supposed to a numpy array:

```
Parameters
fun : callable
A vector function to find a root of.

x0 : ndarray
Initial guess.
```

The root of the problem is that

```
def fun_d(x, d0):
    return(d0 * x)
```

and hence `ode_fun` produces a different result depending on whether `x0` is `np.array(.5)` or `np.array([.5])`.   In the problem cases `ode_fun` returns (2,1) array (or list that becomes that), where as it should be a flat (2,) array.

According to `solve_ivp` docs, the `fun` should return an array that matches `y` in shape,

```
 [If] y: It can either have shape (n,); then fun must return array_like with shape (n,).
```

Thus `ode_fun` should return:

```
return np.ravel([u, v])
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I think I figure out what the problem was.  I will post it here in case someone else has the same problem.

The problem is how `scipy root` function is treating `x0` differently when `krylov` versus other methods is used. For every method other than `krylov` it treats `x0` as an array of length 1 (since in my case I am solving 1 equation and not system of equations).  This might result in broadcasting error mentioned above.  I also report this in `scipy` [github page](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/16724).  This can be resolved by converting `x0` from array to scalar (e.g., with `.item()` method).

Comment: Which `x0` are you talking about.  You pass a scalar `x0=0.5` to root.  Why did you post sample code to the bug report but not here?  And why no tracebacks - here or there?